# Sending emails on behalf of a user and handling invalid addresses

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, spf, email-verification

I have setup a web app that allows subscribers to send emails from my system to their customers.  To do this, I take advantage of the `ReplyTo` function of `PHPMailer`

e.g. MyWebApp.com

```
From: noreply@MyWebApp.com
ReplyTo: subscriber@remotedomain.com
To: customer@yahoo.com
```

This means that all emails that are sent from our system pass all SPAM filters and get delivered with a high rate of accuracy. This appears to satisfy the needs of the subscriber in that, if the customer hits "reply" - the reply is directed to the subscriber: `subscriber@remotedomain.com`

BUT. What I have discovered is that if the subscriber inputs an invalid email address, the
Mail Delivery System Failure Notice is sent to me at `noreply@MyWebApp.com` and not the subscriber `subscriber@remotedomain.com` when it is the subscriber who really needs to know about the problem.

Is there any way, using the setup I have in place, that I can force the Mail Delivery System Failure Notices to go to the intended recipient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Bounces are (or at least should be) sent to the SMTP *envelope sender*, which is the address used in the `MAIL FROM` SMTP command, which is not necessarily the same as the From address in the message headers. In PHPMailer, the from address is used for this by default (since that's what most want), but you can override it using the `Sender` property. You would use it like this:

```php
$mail->setFrom('noreply@MyWebApp.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('subscriber@remotedomain.com');
$mail->addAddress('customer@yahoo.com');
$mail->Sender = 'subscriber@remotedomain.com';
```

This easy enough to say and do, however, it also feeds directly into the mechanism that SPF relies on. SPF does its matching on the envelope sender, not the from address (this is the gap that DMARC bridges), so in order for this to work you would need your customers to add your servers to their domain's SPF records. This is likely to be tricky.

An alternative that doesn't run into SPF issues is to accept bounces to messages you have sent on their behalf, and forward them from your server to them, rather than getting the recipient's server to do that. Be warned though that writing bounce handlers is exceedingly unpleasant!

Comment: Yes, The entire purpose of using our email as the From/Sender is to avoid SPF mismatches and emails not getting delivered. It is rare so dont want to invest a lot of energy building workarounds ... so it looks like I just have to live with it..